# Android Http Client Caching

Tags: android, caching, apache-httpclient-4.x

In my android application I am trying to cache the response of Http Client. I am testing this task using facebook graph api and have the following url: https://graph.facebook.com/riz.ahmed.52

For the first time I get the "first_name" and display it. Then I change the First Name of my facebook profile and call the same link again. I am expecting to get the old/cached "first_name" but I get the updated one. The console always shows the **"The response came from an upstream server"** message when I call the url.

My code for Http Client is as follows:

```
    CacheConfig cacheConfig = new CacheConfig();  
    cacheConfig.setMaxCacheEntries(1000);
    cacheConfig.setMaxObjectSizeBytes(8192);

    //HttpClient httpclient = new CachingHttpClient(new DefaultHttpClient(), cacheConfig);
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

    // Updated code [START]
    httpclient.addResponseInterceptor(new HttpResponseInterceptor() {
        public void process(
            final HttpResponse response,
            final HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {

                 response.removeHeader(response.getFirstHeader("Pragma"));
                 response.removeHeader(response.getFirstHeader("Expires"));

            }                
        });
    // Updated code [END]

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

            // Execute HTTP Get Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    String res = EntityUtils.getContentCharSet(entity);

    CacheResponseStatus responseStatus = (CacheResponseStatus) localContext.getAttribute(
        CachingHttpClient.CACHE_RESPONSE_STATUS);

    switch (responseStatus) {
        case CACHE_HIT:
            System.out.println("A response was generated from the cache with no requests " +
                "sent upstream");
            break;
        case CACHE_MODULE_RESPONSE:
                System.out.println("The response was generated directly by the caching module");
                break;
        case CACHE_MISS:
                System.out.println("The response came from an upstream server");
                break;
        case VALIDATED:
                System.out.println("The response was generated from the cache after validating " +
                        "the entry with the origin server");
                break;
            }
```

I am using **Android 2.3.3**. Please let me know what I am missing here

Answer (score 4):

The page you are loading specifies a `Expires:Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT` header, i.e. it's always considered stale and must always be re-fetched.

**Edit**:

Also returns a `Pragma: no-cache` apparently. Basically, it's telling your HTTP client to never cache this page. You may be able to remove these headers with a [HttpResponseInterceptor](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpResponseInterceptor.html) if you're dead-set on caching the response.

**#2 Edit**:

Using `http-clientcache-4.2.jar` is going to be problematic as it is not completely compatible with the version of the HTTP client packaged with the Android SDK - you're going to get `NoClassDefFoundError`s and similar nonsense when using it.

However - if you "build-your-own" by downloading the source for clientcache-4.2 and strip out any unfulfilled references (such as refactoring the package name of the commons logging)  & killing of all the annotations sprinkled throughout the code (etc.) you can probably get a working version. If you do, this worked:

```
class MakeCacheable implements HttpResponseInterceptor {
    public static MakeCacheable INSTANCE = new MakeCacheable();
    public void process(HttpResponse resp, HttpContext ctx) throws HttpException, IOException {
        resp.removeHeaders("Expires");
        resp.removeHeaders("Pragma");
        resp.removeHeaders("Cache-Control");
    }
}
```

Injected into the `DefaultHttpClient` used by the `CachingHttpClient` like so:

```
DefaultHttpClient realClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
realClient.addResponseInterceptor(MakeCacheable.INSTANCE, 0); // This goes first
CachingHttpClient httpClient = new CachingHttpClient(realClient, cacheConfig);
```

If an entry is cached or not is decided by the `ResponseCachingPolicy` which unfortunately is a `final` in the `CachingHttpClient`, but looking through it will show all the headers that need to go to make an un-cacheable entry cacheable.

Comment: I have removed both the Headers from my response but the results are same

Comment: How did you remove them? If you do it by changing the resulting `HttpResponse` from `HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);` you're probably going to be to late for it to work.

Comment: I am removing it by adding a response interceptor. I have updated my post where I show how i am calling an interceptor

Comment: One more thing. To add a response interceptor I have to change the CachingHttpClinet to DefaultHttpClient. The post is updated

Comment: Hm, since the CachingHttpClient is 4.1 (and Android is shipping that god-awful excuse beta-version of 4.0) I'm assuming you are using a repackaged library - is it one of the public ones, such as `ch.boye`?

Comment: I am adding an external library (apache http-clientcache-4.2.jar) into my android project. I will try to set Target of my android project to 4.0.3 and see how it works.

Comment: @rizzz86 Did you ever have any luck with this?

Comment: @brk3 I have implemented my own cache at that time.